# Align 2 minipage to page margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

I'm trying to align 2 minipages and I still get `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 9--22`

Here is the MWE with a text for reference

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,heightrounded,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\kant[1] %for reference
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{minipage}{0.39\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
\emph{Doctorand:}\\
Maximus \textsc{Stephenson}                             
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.55\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
\emph{Coordonator științific:} \\
Prof. Univ. Dr. Jordan \textsc{Robertson} 
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: remove the ``\\`` after `\end{minipage}` it has no reason to be there as the blank line creates a new paragraph

Comment: Thanks. That part solved the `Underfull \hbox` but it is still not aligned with the text justified.

Comment: Is is the missing alignment with the left edge of the text you are referring to? Add `\noindent` before the first `minipage` I would also use `\hfill` between not `~`.

Comment: minipipage are vertically centred by default use `[t]` if you want them top aligned,

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now they are aligned!